# How to pass value to lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying to combine multiple steps in the parameters of my functions using lambdas. I have tried:

```
void testLambda(const char* input, const char* output = [](const char* word){return word;}(input)){

     std::cout << input << " " << output << std::endl;

}
```

This function is supposed to: if

```
testLambda("hallo");
```

is called, take from the first argument and create a second parameter (default) out it and print `hallo hallo`.
How can i make this work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `const char* output = nullptr){if output == nullptr){output = input;}`. Why a lambda?

Comment: You can't refer to other parameters from a default argument. Use an overload that forwards them instead.

Comment: Actually in the function an outputfile needed to be created and it's name need to change according to the input file name, which come in the first paramater. I wanted to give the user the change to either input a name, and the output file name get generated automatically with this lambda function as default value or  the user can simply input the output file name manually.   I solved this issue using simple function, but wanted to know if my test example was also possible

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that — default arguments aren't sophisticated enough. Even if they were, this wouldn't be terribly clear code.

Just write an overload!

```
void testLambda(const char* input, const char* output)
{
     std::cout << input << ' ' << output << '\n';
}

void testLambda(const char* input)
{
    return testLambda(input, input);
}
```

Or if you don't want to do that:

```
void testLambda(const char* input, const char* output = nullptr)
{
     std::cout << input << ' ' << (output ? output : input) << '\n';
}
```

*(And then rename the function :P)*

There's no need to make this pattern complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already solved this using the normal way. I just wanted to test if this was possible. The issue is that i want to generate default values depending on the first given parameter without written a full function for that.

Comment: @AKJ: Just hive it off into a function, and call the function if you need to. Keep it simple. Your readers will thank you.